# Is there some way to create a class that have an object of a class that have an object of this class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, attributes

In C++, is there some way to create a class that have, as attribute, an object of a class that have, as attribute, an object of the first class?

e.g.:

```
class A {
    B attribute;
public:
    A(){}
};

class B {
    A attribute;
public:
    B(){}
};
```

The code above does not compile. Is there some way to do something alike?

Thanks!

Comment: No language would be able to represent such infinite number of attributes.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm coming here to ask for help! Actually my sctructure need to have two classes that have attributes of each other types, but the recursion will end some time (like "a class A may have OR NOT a class B as attribute" and same for B, but I don't know how to do this), I'm not trying to do an inifinite loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to forward declare your class B. If not, the compiler wouldn't know what the B is. Also, change the attributes to be pointers, or else you will still have a compiler error, even though you forward declared B, it still doesn't know the implementation yet!

The following code may help, good luck...

```
class B;

class A {
    B *attribute;
public:
    A(){}
};

class B {
    A *attribute;
public:
    B(){}
};
```

Comment: This will allow you to compile but still for `A`, `B` instantiation, compiler **must** see their definitions. Forward declarations just don't suffice.

Comment: Of course, somewhere in your code you need to instantiate the objects for A and B and set them as proper attributes for the instances of the corresponding classes!

Answer (score 2):

These definitions, even if you could use forward declaration to make them work (which you can't), are inherently recursive.  An A contains a B, which contains an A, which contains a B, and on and on.  It is nonsensical.

Comment: if you used pointers with forward declarations - you could make them work. Still - definitely need to look at the design though...

Comment: Yeah, this is just an exemple. I want to make the recursion end some time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your structure. You're trying to define a structure that contains another structure, which contains the first structure which contains the second structure, etc...